# How is the lookahead for an LR(1) automaton computed?

Tags: compilers, parsers, lr-k

I'm reading Douglas Thain's book called "Introduction to Compilers and Language Design" and I've come across the following grammar:

[image]

, with the following LR(1) automaton:

[image]

, and I am not sure the look-ahead sets in state 0 (or any other state, really) is computed.

The algorithm given is the following:

```
For an item like A → α.B with a lookahead of {L}, add new rules
like B → .γ with a lookahead of {L}.
• For an item like A → α.Bβ, with a lookahead of {L}, add new rules
like B → .γ with a lookahead as follows:
– If β cannot produce epsilon, the lookahead is FIRST(β).
– If β can produce epsilon, the lookahead is FIRST(β) ∪ {L}
```

I don't really understand what FIRST(β) is in the case where β = + E (since E -> E + T is of the form A-> α.Bβ)

Also, it seems to me that `+ T` *cannot* produce epsilon, then how is it that its lookahead is `{$,+}` ? (which seems like it's `FIRST(β) ∪ {L}`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\text{FIRST}(\beta)$ is the set of possible first tokens in a derivation from β. (It's usual to also add ε to the first set if β could derive the empty sequence.)

So $\text{FIRST}(\mathbf{+}\mathit{T})$ is $\{\mathbf{+}\}$. No other token could possibly be at the beginning of any sentence derived from $\mathbf{+}\mathit{T}$. If that's not clear, it would be useful if you could explain your confusion.

The lookahead for an item is the set of tokens which could immediately follow the *complete* production of the item. It has absolutely nothing to do with the • in the item, but it's really only meaningful if the • is at the end (and therefore the state containing the item could be reduced). Giving every item a lookahead set is an algorithmic convenience for certain ways of computing lookahead sets, but in the completed state machine the only place lookahead sets are relevant is in the reduction states.

It might, however, make it easier to understand how lookahead sets are computed:

- Conceptually, lookahead sets are created during the itemset closure operation. Closure (recursively) creates new items with the • at the beginning for every non-terminal $\mathit{N}$ which follows the • in some item in the state. The new items are precisely the productions for $\mathit{N}$. Each such item is annotated with the lookahead for $\mathit{N}$ in the existing item; in other words, the lookahead set tells us what symbols could follow the new item when it's finished (at which point we'll come back to this state in order to take the GOTO action for $\mathit{N}$). If the item already exists in the state (because $\mathit{N}$ was previously encountered during the closure operation), we don't add a new item; instead, we add the symbols from the follow set for this instance of $\mathit{N}$ to the lookahead set for the new item.

  As an example, consider State 12 in your diagram. The first item is $\mathit{T}\to\;\mathbf{id} \;\mathbf{(}\;•\;\mathit{E}\;\mathbf{)}$, in which $\mathit{E}$ follows the •. So we're going to add items for each production for $\mathit{E}$, and all of those new items will be given the lookahead set $\{\mathbf{)}\}$, because that's what follows the $\mathit{E}$ here. So that causes us to add the item, $\mathit{E}\to\; •\; \mathit{E}\; \mathbf{+}\; \mathit{E}$. Since we've already added items for the productions of $\mathit{E}$, we don't add new ones; however, we must add $\mathbf{+}$ to all their lookahead sets, because that's the symbols which follows *this* instance of $\mathit{E}$. So now the lookahead sets for the new $\mathit{E}$ items are $\{ \mathbf{+}, \mathbf{)} \}$. There are no more instances of $\mathit{E}$ following the •, so those lookahead sets are now complete.
- When we create a new state by advancing the •, we  simply copy the lookahead sets for each item in the new state. So the lookahead sets still reflect what the possible following symbols are when the item's production is completed.

  But note that the LALR algorithm merges states with the same items, independent of the items' lookahead sets. In the resulting merged state, the lookahead set for each item is the union of the lookahead set for each item in the states being merged. This is actually imprecise, which is why LALR parsers can have conflicts which don't appear in the LR parser for the same grammar (in which states with different lookahead sets are not merged). However, it's not *fatally* imprecise; it cannot cause a valid derivation to be discarded, but it can cause the parser to perform a reduction step which will lead it to limbo.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer. I've also missed a helpful point in the book which states the following: "One aspect of state zero is worth clarifying. When constructing the
closure of a state, we must consider all rules in the grammar, including
the rule corresponding to the item under closure." Things are much clearer now.